# Conditional For Loop PHP

Tags: php

If Condition A is True use set A, conditions **for** loop, If false use set B, conditions for the **for** loop.

```
if ($_POST['Latest'] == 1): 
    for ($i=$date_to; $i>=$date_from; $i-=86400)  
else:  
    for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) 
endif;
```

This code gives me a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE.

Comment: Um, obviously you can't do that

Comment: What do you expect your loops to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if ($_POST['Latest'] == 1){ 
          for ($i=$date_to; $i>=$date_from; $i-=86400){
             // EXECUTE SOME CODE...
          }
      }else{
          for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400){
             // EXECUTE SOME CODE...
          }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the proper code:

```
if ($_POST['Latest'] == 1) { 
    for ($i=$date_to; $i>=$date_from; $i-=86400) {
        // do stuff
    }
} else {  
    for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need either to add something after the for loop, add curly brackets or better yet use better syntax, as the previous answers suggest.

The for without curly brackets loops the next statement. So basicaly you try to "else" `$date_from` times.

Your code should work like this though:

```
if ($_POST['Latest'] == 1): 
    for ($i=$date_to; $i>=$date_from; $i-=86400) {}
else:  
    for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) {}
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may look for syntax like:

```
$l = (int) filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Latest', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
for (
  $i = ($l ? $date_from : $date_to);
  $l ? $i >= $date_from : $i <= $date_to;
  $i += 86400 * ($l ? -1 : 1)
):
  continue;
endfor;
```